# Cached shopping cart after going back using the browser

Tags: symfony, shopping-cart

I have a shopping cart that I created by myself. My doubt: how to solve the problem of the cached shopping cart? I mean when I go a page of a product and I added it to the cart, and go back using the browser button, the added product is not on the cart. I have to refresh the page to see it on the cart.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point of making it all right you should set proper headers on response when shopping cart is created/updated, which will instruct browser to not cache it.

```
    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    return $response;
```